# How to load CSS asynchronously - WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am trying load `CSS` asynchronously but the below code not load the `CSS`. Why?

Got the source from [here](https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/4abc92e153b3cf3e146c)

```
function loadCSS(href, before, media) {
    "use strict";
    var ss = window.document.createElement("link");
    var ref = before || window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    ss.rel = "stylesheet";
    ss.href = href;
    ss.media = "only x";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(ss, ref);
    setTimeout(function() {
        ss.media = media || "all";
    });
    return ss;
}

// here's where you specify the CSS files to be loaded asynchronously

// load Google Web Font 
loadCSS("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans");
```

Function:

```
function load_scripts_and_styles() {

    // register loadCSS
    wp_register_script( 'load-css-async', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/loadCSS.js', array(), '', false );

    // enqueue loadCSS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'load-css-async' );

}
```

Comment: Are there console error messages? Or does this just fail quietly?

Comment: There is no errors in the console

Comment: The Script has no error i checked in the console. The 'load_script_and_styles()' function has the error

Comment: Are you trying to execute load_scripts_and_styles() as JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: use add_action .. add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', load_scripts_and_styles', 100 );

Comment: @kshetline as PHP

Comment: @rmarif tried but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with your `http://fonts.googleapis.com` try with some other css file. seems working fine.

```
function loadCSS(href, before, media) {
    "use strict";
    var ss = window.document.createElement("link");
    var ref = before || window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    ss.rel = "stylesheet";
    ss.href = href;
    ss.media = "only x";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(ss, ref);
    setTimeout(function() {
        ss.media = media || "all";
    });     
    return ss;
}

// here's where you specify the CSS files to be loaded asynchronously

loadCSS("http://localhost/demowp/wp-content/themes/sydney/css/file.css");
```

Comment: Yes! tried the problem is not with the script. The issue is with wp_enqueue_script. Do you find any error in wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: seems `http://fonts.googleapis.com` font included already in your theme. that is issue.

Comment: But others CSS also not loading